# Delphi 2009 (and probably Delphi 2010 as well) and QTP

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, qtp

We have a suite of automatic tests written in QTP (Quick Test Pro - an HP product), and we have just upgraded to Delphi 2009 (I know we are late adopters), and all of these tests no longer work. The plugin that QTP have released does not work with Delphi 2009 - we have that in writing now from HP. Do you know of (a) anyone else in the same boat as us (b) anyone have a work around, as I can't see one and HP don't seem to be too proactive about this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the same problem with WinRunner as well. The problem has actually been solved. We editted the plugin source so that it responds properly to UniCode strings, and it all works properly. Not sure whether legally we are allowed to publish (or indeed do) this, but it enables us to use WinRunner / QTP, so I don't see how anyone can complain!

Comment: Bravo! It would have been great if QTP Architects (e.g. `Roy Nuriel`) communicated to you for sharing your solution. Delphi support is actually a bunch of sources written in Object Pascal. It has extensibility foundation though, so potential for customization is considerable.

Comment: Updated - I have found this patch which makes the same changes as we made, and it is an official HP one as well! http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Functional-Testing-QTP/New-QTP-11-Public-Patch-Support-Testing-Delphi-2009-and-2010/td-p/2406166

Answer (score 1):

I hate to admit it but if QTP completely doesn't work with Delphi 2009 you have to try TestComplete. If you still want to have QTP as your main tool you should try launching TestComplete's tests from QTP through COM automation.

Thanks.

Comment: Only problem is, use of QTP isn't my decision - the testing team have the expertise, if only it actually supported the application development environment we actually use!

Comment: I'm a happy test complete user. AutomatedQA is a delphi-friendly company.