# Delphi XE and Winrunner (QTP)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, qtp

We have a suite of automatic tests written in winrunner (QTP), and we have just upgraded to Delphi XE. I tried to modify TestSrvr.pas, MercControl.pas and MercCustControl.pas to manage unicode but I've still some problem. When I launch Winrunner I find "class" and "Label" but not anymore the "Delph_Name" and all automatic test use the "Delph_Name". 
Does anyone have the same problem? 
How do you update the Winrunner plugin to be compatible with DelphiXE ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Delphi plugin doesn't properly support Unicode. See [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333552/delphi-2009-and-probably-delphi-2010-as-well-and-qtp) and lack of answer. It isn't quite the answer to your problem, but it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: yes I saw this thread. The problem is I can't use TestComplete. I have to use Winrunner because of history of my project. I read your answer where you notice than you "editted the plugin source so that it responds properly to UniCode strings, and it all works properly". Could you explain me how? I have to modify one of the 3 delphi's file, or is it more complicated? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've found this as well (http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Functional-Testing-QTP/New-QTP-11-Public-Patch-Support-Testing-Delphi-2009-and-2010/td-p/2406166). It seems to patch the Delphi code that is used to attach to QTP - I'm gonna get this checked out because maybe I can stop using the home grown patches. I'll let you know by posting here

Comment: Thank you for the link but it's a dead end. My company didn't have support anymore for this product, Because we are changing our testing tool :-(. Do you know which function of testsrv, MercControl or MercCustControl send informations to winrunner ?

Comment: No, we changed from WinRunner TO QTP!

Comment: OK. :-s I can't use QTP, so I continue to search in the Winrunner's code :'(